# What is the difference between using Linux VRF, network namespaces and using different routing tables?

Tags: networking, routing, iproute, network-namespaces

The ip-vrf manual reads :

> A VRF provides traffic isolation at layer 3 for routing, similar to how a VLAN is used to isolate traffic at layer 2. Fundamentally, a VRF is a separate routing table.

At the same time, The iproute2 `ip` command allows to deal with multiple separate routing tables by using the `table` keyword.

Moreover, Linux network namespaces, which have been popularized by containers, also allow to separate routing tables (and devices, and […]).

So what's the difference between VRFs and iproute2's multiple routing tables, and network namespaces ? Are there some things you can do with one and not the other ? Or is that fundamentally the same mechanism with different names ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no short answer for this, https://www.google.se/search?q=linux+vrf+vs+namespace is a good start. I found [this post](https://www.dasblinkenlichten.com/working-with-linux-vrfs/) useful.

If you over-simplify;

Network namespaces - complete network isolation. Use in containers

VRF - Use when "tenants" need different default routes

Routing tables - As opposed to the above this is not network isolation but a generic mechanism used for instance for policy routing, see `man ip-rule`. E.g. source based policy routing